# Using a python script, how do I read the output of a bash script it launched if that script that never ends

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I am making a python program that launches a bash script that shows debugging signals of another program. What I want my python program to do is read the debugging info the bash script is sending out, so python can parse it to make it more human-readable.

However, the thing is that I can't find a way to get the output of that bash script. The bash script itself never ends on its own, so the usual methods ( like subprocess.Popen ) I keep finding of reading an output from a bash script didn't seem to work.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: `popen` should work fine as long as you don't block on the end of the pipe when there isn't data there.

Comment: I would be somewhat tempted to do something like `bash script | python script` and just make the python script read from `stdin`

Comment: (so something of the form `yes | python test.py `)

Comment: If all else fails, you can pipe the output to `tee,` and then read the updated file from disk.